# make elements block if parents are flex boxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

[image]

## JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/bnfsnm40/

Markup:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">Download stats</div>
  <div class="card-block">
      <div class="statistics">
          <span class="day statistic">
              <div class="count">100</div>
              <div class="rank">10th</div>
              <div class="icon text-success">
                  <i class="fa fa-line-chart "></i>
                  +4
              </div>
           </span>
```

What i want to do:

`count`, `rank` and `icon`should be `display: block`so they are under each other. 
if i set them display: block they simply do not act like i expect a normal block element will act, they still sit next to each other rather then top to bottom.

```
.card-block {
  .statistics {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
   .statistic {
      height: 65px;
      display: flex;
      .count {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .rank {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

Comment: First of all - never strip closing tags out of your example. There is room for improvement in your `flexbox` settings. However, you can try and set them to `inline-block` with a width of `100%`.

Comment: @Sqnkov i am new and learning about flexbox today. please tell me what to improve.

Comment: @Sqnkov `inline-block`won't change any behaviour

Comment: Add the full fragments of your code first. All the way to the closing tags. Now anyone willing to help must type all the missing characters.

Comment: @Sqnkov this is pretty much full fragment of my code

Comment: have a look at flex-direction.  If you want to stack your divs, change it to column.  There are a lot of good explanations about flex out there - a simple search for it will bring up lots of complete guides to it.  Have you tried reading onee or did you just think you would post here before doing any research

Comment: @Pete well, i just saw if i change `.statistic` to be a div and remove the flex display, then it's working as expected. strange.

Comment: @Pete i did add a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bnfsnm40/

Comment: @Sqnkov i did add a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bnfsnm40/

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options for flex displaying items so they are "under" each other vertically.

Option 1 - Set `flex-wrap:wrap;` on the parent container and `width:100%;` on the children.

Option2 - Set `flex-direction:column;` on the parent container.